# Laravel does not throw 404 when route ends with .php

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.5, varnish

I using Laravel 5.5 in conjunction with NGINX 1.10.3 and Varnish 5.

Everytime I type in a route, which does not exist, laravel throws a `404` exception and my custom `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` is shown.

The problem is, that when I append `.php` to the route, which does not exists, I get a

```
File not found.
```

message from NGINX. How is it possible to display my custom `404.blade.php` even when `.php` is appanded to a not existing route?

Maybe I should rewrite the varnish VCL in order to cut off the trailing `.php` and then pass the request to the backend (NGINX)?

Comment: Can you show yor nginx and varnish configuration?

Comment: Why do you want your routes to end in .php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You PHP script handler location should look like this, to achieve what you want:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri /index.php =404;
    ...
}
```

The `try_files` is essential here to route requests for non-existing .php scripts through the Laravel `index.php` handler (which will do its not-found magic).

Answer (score 0):

inside your **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {


        if($this->isHttpException($exception)){
                switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
                    case 400:
                        return redirect('/');
                    case 404:
                        return view('errors.404');  // your 404 error page
                        break;
                }
        } 
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: It does not work. For "normal" 404, yes - but the problem is that laravel does not understand the `.php` at the end and delegates the request to NGINX.